# How to convert shorthand CSS to longhand?

Tags: css, css-sprites

Is there any tool which can automatically convert shorthand css to longhand? I need this cause I want to use [SmartSprites](http://csssprites.org/) which does not work well with shorthand.

And prefably also a tool which does the reverse, so after the sprite computation i can minify the css as much as possible...

Also any other solutions for automatic spiriting is welcome, basically im looking for some command line tools which can be integrated into the build process so that the developers still develop on the raw css code.

Comment: Do you mean shorthand like `margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;` would go to `margin-left:0px`, etc. Or shorthand as in a minified version of the CSS where an element declaration is all on one line? such as `#element {margin:0px}`.

Comment: The first one... i.e. margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; would go to margin-left:0px, etc....
The second one is not so important and its easy to implement using regex...

Comment: That would be a nice [code golf](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20736/what-is-code-golf-on-stack-overflow) question

Comment: If it's only things like margin, border and padding I would do some string processing in python. Parse the values and mash it together as you like. Validate and visually check it and do the rest of the tweaks by hand.

The other option is to use a javascript to find the css styles of each element. Not sure that can be done though.

Firebug might come in handy with it's computed values tab.

Comment: Thats my plan for tomorrow. Since i am only interested in the background: shorthand, I intend to make something in python to take in the raw css and parse the 'background:' elements.. any python modules gonna make my life easier? or I should stick with good ol regex? the javascript and firebug ways wont work cause the css has a lot of unused elements in it which need to stay there for now.

Comment: I think regex should be fine. Get the lines that match margin: x x x x; and split it by the spaces. Remove the line and insert "margin-top:" + values[0] etc. 

There is this css parser for python: http://cssutils.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/html/index.html

Depending on how long your css is it would probably be easier to use string functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Dragonfly on Opera. Dragonfly is like Firebug on Firefox and Chrome but developed by Opera. There is a function in Dragonfly which let you alter the shorthand and vica versa. Check [opera.com/dragonfly/documentation/](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/documentation/)

Answer (score 0):

For the reverse, you can use a CSS optimiser like [csstidy](http://csstidy.sourceforge.net/). I doubt it will convert shorthands to non-shorthands though.

Why not forbid the use of shorthands by developers and use csstidy in the build process?

If you don't like that idea, you could write a small script to do the shorthand conversion, which is significantly easier than the other way around. It basically comes down to string replacement.

Comment: From what ive tried... csstidy doesn't convert shorthand to the long version. 

The css comes from the clients existing site and will be completely re-written in the future(without shorthand)... for now I have to make do with the existing css... which is full of shorthand css. Far too many to elongate by hand.

Since I am only interested in elongating the background property, I'll try to write something in python.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think csstidy would do it that way around either. Good luck with the script!